# BackroundWorker with progressbar would not fire RunWorkerCompleted

Tags: c#, asynchronous, sqlconnection

I know this question has been asked before but I couldn't find the answers. I have a backroundworker that loads the progress bar and executes a method that checks a sql connection.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
          {
              BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

          for (int i = 1; (i <= 100); i++)
          {
                  // Perform a time consuming operation and report progress.
                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(25);
                  worker.ReportProgress((i));

                  if ( i == 75) 
                  CheckConnection();
          }


      }

      private void backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
      {

          this.progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
      }

      private void backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Checked");
      }
```

And the CheckConnection method

```
 private void CheckConnection()
    {
        string response = "";
        //Check if Windows authentification or SQL Autentificaion and create the connection string
        if (AuthMode == 1)
        {
            ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + Server + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=SSPI;";
        }
        else
        {
            ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + Server + ";Initial Catalog=master;User ID=" + Username + ";Password=" + Password+ "";
        }

        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            response = "Connection successfull for: " + ConnectionString;
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException e)
        {
            response = "Connection failed for: " + ConnectionString + e.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(response);

        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            response = "Connection failed for: " + ConnectionString + e.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(response);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            response = "Connection failed for: " + ConnectionString + e.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(response);

        }

    }
```

The progress bar loads nicely but the RunWorkerCompleted does not fire. Any idea why? Thanks

Edited:
I call backroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync() on a button click.

```
 private void btnChkCon_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
          backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); 
        }
```

**EDIT**

Found the problem, backgroundWorker1_RunWorkerCompleted was not binded to the BackroundworkerCompleted event, it works now.

Comment: I cant see hoe your events are wire but it looks a bit suspicious , that the event is named bw_ProgressChanged instead of backgroundWorker1_ProgressChanged maybe you have two background workers

Comment: I agree with @Wize, the naming convention used the completed handler is  totally different to that used for the rest of the events. Even if wired up correctly, it would be better to keep them all unified I think. Perhaps you could post some code on where you create the worker thread, and add its event handlers

Comment: Changed the names, still the workerCompleted would not fire. I`ve added the worker call.